# How to parse DateTime.now() into hh:mm:ss format in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I cannot seem to be able to parse the date obtained from `DateTime.now()` in the `hh:mm:ss` format. When I do, I get the below error:

```
Uncaught Error: FormatException: Trying to read : from 2022-12-05 15:40:34.987 at position 5
```

This here is my code:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  var now = DateTime.now();
  DateFormat inputFormat = DateFormat('hh:mm:ss');
  var current = inputFormat.parse(now.toString());
  print(current);
}
```

I would like to know what I need to do to get the time in the mentioned format.

Answer (score 0):

By using intl package

```
  var now = DateTime.now();
  DateFormat inputFormat = DateFormat('hh:mm:ss');
  var current = inputFormat.format(now);
  print(current);
```

Answer (score 0):

`parse` used when you want to convert `string` to `dateTime`, but I assume what you want is converting `dateTime` (now) to string format. you need to use  `format` like this:

```
print("date = ${DateFormat.Hms().format(DateTime.now())}"); //date = 14:05:41
```

Comment: @coolhack7 was it what you looking for?